# retain CKEditor scroll bar at cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using the similar code to retain cursor position for ckeditor.

```
var range = null;
editor.on( 'blur', function() {
    range = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[ 0 ];
});
someElement.on('click',function() {
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
 if(editor){
    editor.focus();
    range.select();  
 }
});
```

I'm able to retain cursor position but the scrollbar scrolls to the top.
How can i keep/retain the scrollbar at same position as of cursor's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range.select().scrollIntoView()` helped me out!!

Answer (score 0):

I have several editors on a long page, and `scrollIntoView()` never did exaclty what I wanted: either it scrolled laso the container page, or it doesn't, or it puts the elemnt to show just one line after the viewport... so, since my need was simply to return to the previous position after a small change in the HTML with `setData()`, I could do the following:

```
    let window = editor.document.getWindow().$ ;
    let scrollX = window.scrollX ;
    let scrollY = window.scrollY ;
[...]
    editor.setData(contents, {
        callback: function() {
            editor.document.getWindow().$.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY) ;
        }
    }) ;
```

I don't think that CKEditor (at least, not the 4.x series) has the proper APIs for this, so I had to go to the underlying DOM.